# Wordpress widget does not display

Tags: php, wordpress, widget

I have such a problem. On single.php page template, I display posts by categories. At the sidebar, I have the widget with related services and a bunch of tags that where I can filter displayed tags(using GET requests)
It looks like this:

```
<aside class='main__aside'>
  <?php the_widget('some_wdgt',
                    array('title' => esc_html__('title', 'domain'),
                          'nav_menu' => 772));
  ?>
  <?php
    ... some code with get params ...
  ?>
</aside>
```

Everything works fine, but when I apply filter widget with menu filter disappears. The only title of the widget is displayed.
Insdide widget code I display meny via:

```
...
echo $before_widget;
if ( $title ) {
  echo $before_title . $title . $after_title;
}
wp_nav_menu( apply_filters( 'widget_nav_menu_args', $nav_menu_args, $nav_menu, $args, $instance ) );
echo $after_widget;
```

Why this is happening and how can I fix it? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

May be it happens because of $nav_menu is WP_Term object, not number.

Please, look at this: [widget_nav_menu_args](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/widget_nav_menu_args/). Hope it helps

Comment: No, that's not because of that. on wp-kama it says that 'nav_menu' can be a string or id number. I have changed it to menu name. The result is the same. When I have GEt request only title from widget is displayed.

Comment: as i can see nav_menu mus be WP_Term{} object. not int or string 

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_term/


https://wp-kama.ru/hook/widget_nav_menu_args